# Can multiple rows with the same ID be updated at the same time, with one query?

Tags: mysql

I've made an Update Query for 1 table. Now in this table, I have just 2 columns, ID and Value. Each ID has at least 1 value but can have multiple.

Example

```
ID // VALUE
1 //   100
1 //    200
2 //    400
3 //    300
3 //    500
```

So the ID is not unique in the table but the way we update the values is by ID
So we would get some data like ID 3 Value 600, 700 , So after updating the result would be like this:

```
ID // VALUE
1 //   100
1 //    200
2 //    400
3 //    600
3 //    700
```

Frankly, it doesn't matter which one gets updated with each value as long as it is the ones with the Given ID (in this case 3 )
The ID can be repeated even in 6-10 rows
So now we have to update the values of the two rows with ID 3
My problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to update every row when the ID is the same
So how would I go to the next ID and update that one's value?
I've created a simple for loop that adds a string in the middle of the Query so for each Value (can be 1 or can be more) given there is a `"WHEN ID THEN new_value"` that looks like this

```
 for  ( const new_value of VALUE) {
           PartialQuery += ` WHEN ${ID} THEN ${new_value}`;
          }
FinalQuery  = `UPDATE Table1 SET VALUE = CASE ${PartialQuery} END WHERE ID IN (3)`;
```

And then When I run the query I get a query syntax error
I've tried adding GROUP BY at the end by table or by ID but it doesn't seem to work
Is this even doable without having a unique ID?

Comment: Print the `FinalQuery` that is actually executed.  Also, what is the actual error message? syntax error where?

Comment: Not possible because your data has no way if establishing which row for id should be updated , consider fixing your data.

Comment: @Kaii it says syntax error '' , so with an empty string , I think the problem is that I'm trying to change 2 values with the same ID but isn't there any way to "go" to the second one and so on and pass the one I've already changed ?

Comment: @P.Salmon Isn't there a way to pass the rows that I've already changed ?

Comment: That's the problem you don't know which one to update if id/amount combo is unique you might get away with an update LIMIT but that looks unsafe to me.

Comment: @P.Salmon What if we had other tables that have both of these data , would it be possible that those could help to differentiate and change the data ? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Perhaps you have oversimplified the question - if the published sample data comes from a number of tables then you should show sample data from those tables.

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version? What is precise data format (I mean your "data like ID 3 Value 600, 700" - in what format you can provide it into the query)? Does ID and VALUE are the only columns in the table?

Comment: @Akina they are the only columns, and they are varchar

Comment: print the final query generated. Your CASE condition seems to be incomplete, but i can only tell when i see the final query. PRINT IT.

Comment: `UPDATE tbl SET field = "value" WHERE ID = 3` would update both rows with ID=3. This is the default behaviour.

Comment: Also, `VALUE` is a bad choice for a column name, because `VALUE` is a reserved keyword. You need to escape the column name. (i.e. `SET \`VALUE\` = "content"`, note the backticks)   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 0):

OK, before I provide a workable answer, I should stress - unique identifying fields are required for a number of reasons and it is bad practice to not have them.

I suspect the table you have is using "id" as a foreign identifier, and in which case, would usually be named with the foreign table table followed by id. For example, an order table would have "id" for its own identifier. The order items would have their own "id" field for their identifiers and a "order_id" field as the foreign key field.

### Solution

As mentioned by many before me, an id is required to update. Not entirely true, as you can have an incrementing number within the statement, but it's more hassle than it is worth.

Instead, if you really want to work on a table without a unique identifier, you can delete all matching rows and insert them a fresh with their new values. If you're worried about integrity, wrap it all in a DB transaction.

Alternatively, if at the point of updating you know the old value, you can update with multiple parts in the where, so `WHERE ID IN (3) AND VALUE = 300` - however, this requires that all rows have unique id/value combinations, which I suspect your table does not.